# Can I release a modified version of a patented product?

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, design-patent

Assume there are some patents out there that seem to be fundamental and almost trivial.

Can I patent and/or manufacture a product that builds on a patented product (I don't own the "basic" patent)

For example, there are a lot of patented power supply strips that turn off devices based on a "master" device's power draw (your computer peripherals switch off if the "master" computer goes into standby).

I want to build "smart remote" power supply strips that not only does the above **but also** can be configured over WiFi and household remote control (so that you can turn your power-hungry fax machine on/off remotely or while watching TV)

If I build my version of "smart remote" power supply strips am I infringing on the existing patented power supply strips?

Answer (score 2):

Getting a patent issued on your improved widget doesn't affect the rights of someone who has a patent on the basic widget. So yes, you may very well infringe something if this is an area thick with granted, in-force patents.

Comment: I dont understand this. In that case livescribe (digital pen) is infringing on the patents held by Reynolds (ballpoint pen)

Comment: A smart pen is still a pen. If the writing particulars of a smart pen are "read on" by the claims of a in-force pen patent they area either licensing it or infringing it.

Comment: Does this mean that the person who patented the AC motor is getting rich just from licensing deals from companies making electrical juicers, grinders, fans, ventialtors, ... ?

Comment: Patents expire. Nikolai Tesla filed a patent for an AC motor design in 1888 and likely received cash for it for quite a few years. New US patents currently have a term of 20 years, where the start date is usually the patent's filing date.